# checking if time set is greater than current time?

Tags: android

The time will be saved as string, is there any way to convert the string into time and then check if its equal to or greater than current time, or if its less than current time?

Sorry if this has been asked many times before!

Comment: Are you actually using System.currentTimeMillis(); Then @ninetwozero's answer would be correct, unless you are referring to as in `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format?

Answer (score 4):

**This how you convert a string to date format:**

I've supposed that you use the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setLenient(false); 

String oldTime = "2012-07-11 10:55:21";
Date oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
```

**This is how you get the current Time**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Finally This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/) will show you how to compare dates in java

Answer (score 1):

Is the time saved as a timestamp in String form, or an actual String? If it's the timestamp, you could always do the following:

```
long timestamp = Long.parseLong(stringTimestamp);
```

Comment: *the matrix* has found you! LOL ;) (for others that don't get the joke... ah well!)

Comment: @t0mm13b I see no blue pill though!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct but outdated. Use java.time classes instead.

## `LocalTime`

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day.

```
LocalTime input = LocalTime.parse( "20:15" );
```

To get the current time-of-day, specify a time zone. For any given moment, the time-of-day varies by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( zoneId );
```

You can compare using the `equals`, `compareTo`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean input isAfterNow = input.isAfter( now );
```

You can generate a String to represent this time-of-day value in standard ISO 8601 format with a 24-hour clock `HH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSS`. Just call `toString`.

```
String output = now.toString();
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java SimpleDateFormat class to convert from String to Date and compare from there.

```
String raw = "July 13 2012 08:43:12";

Date parsedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(raw);

Date currentDate = new Date();

boolean isafter = parsedDate.after(currentDate);
```

Comment: after coverting how would i check if its greather than current time or less than? i throught i seen somewhere that there .after function?

Comment: boolean isafter = parsedDate.after(currentDate);

Answer (score 0):

```
//t1.toDate().before( Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
t1.toDate().after(  Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```